# How can we identify a unique record in Cassandra for tables which don't have a primary key defined?

Tags: cassandra

I have **Cassandra** database and some tables within it. Tables don't have primary key / unique key / composite key defined. How can we identify a unique record in a table?

Like oracle has concept of ROWID , in same way do we have something for Cassandra database. N/A

Comment: There must be a primary key on the table (consisting of a partition key and potentially a clustering key) - but its not possible to not have a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to create Cassandra tables without a primary key defined.

The partition key in the primary key dictates how each record is "partitioned" or distributed among nodes in the cluster. Without a partition key, Cassandra doesn't know how to store the data in the cluster.

Here's an example table that is partitioned by email address:

```
CREATE TABLE users_by_email (
    email text,
    firstname text,
    lastname text,
    PRIMARY KEY (email)
)
```

In this example, it will not be possible to read or write to the table without knowing a user's email address.

For more info on how Cassandra distributes data across nodes in a cluster, see [Partitioners in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/architecture/archPartitionerAbout.html). There is also this short video on [how Cassandra stores data in partitions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np5RJpCiCzM&list=PL2g2h-wyI4Spf5rzSmesewHpXYVnyQ2TS&index=3) (extracted from the **DS201 Cassandra Foundations** course at [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com)). Cheers!